# Netbeans IDE font

Tags: netbeans

Is it possible to enlarge the font of the Netbeans screens themselves (not the editor font)?
I tried to find a reference to "font" in the menu-items "Tools" and "Window"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the "system font size" (menus, dialogs etc) using the command line parameter `--fontsize` when starting NetBeans, e.g. `--fontsize 14`